# Leading zeros in an int column gets removed when converted to string – python

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

The title here basically explains my issue/ask, I have an int column with more than 12 digits that starts with leading zeros. my problem is that when i convert these values to string some values lose their leading zeros which are essential for analysis purposes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Yrj.png
[This is the column, as saved and extracted from a database.

I want to convert these values as is starting with zeros. I only use .astype(str) for the type conversion: (df['trxn'] = df['trxn'].astype(str). Any advice?

the idea is that after analyzing the dataset we will be uploading those trxn id/numbers into a system to match with the records we have in our database, so it must contain those leading zeros as saved in the database to get the matched records.

Here is an example of how it originally looks like, in DB and csv file:
|Trxn|
|---------------------|
|009907023031022180158|

This is how it's returned in python:
|Trxn|
|---------------------|
| 9907023031022180158 |

Comment: Specific examples and code that reproduces the problem would help people to give you useful answers

Comment: Where did the 0s come from? Actual integers don't have leading 0s in either Python nor pandas.

Comment: Really? It's not possible with python to have integers with leading 0 else it will raise `SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just edited the post with an image of how the data looks like when i first read the csv file

Comment: Paste in some python code that produces two rows of example data which reproduces the symptom you observe. If we can’t run it and see the problem, we can’t test a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not python. It's just how integers work. Leading zeroes have no mathematical significance.

You can use some built in string methods to pad a string to a particular length filling with an arbitrary character like so:

```
>>> x = "000002"                        
>>> print x
2
>>> x =  str(x).rjust(6,'0')  #adds 5 leading zeroes to x
>>> print x
000002
```

Or you can use `.zfill()`

```
number= '2' 
print number.zfill(5) #adds 4 leading zeroes to the string
>>> 00002
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but how do i apply this to the whole column and keep it as is in a way that when i save the desired result and upload it back to DB it can still appear with those zeros? right now it's causing an issue when i upload it to match the saved values with the DB records, it returns a high % of unmatched values

Comment: @Shrouq For a whole column do: `df['trxn'] = df['trxn'].astype('str').str.zfill(25)` - the 25 is just for illustration, you have to determine what length to use.